# Modifying a list of fields with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy

I have a list of fields from a dataset which are string type fields.
I need to remove empty spaces from all rows in these fields.

My code is:

```
import arcpy
dataset = r'Database Connections\xxxx.sde\GISUSA.PET_Wells'
fields = arcpy.ListFields(dataset)
for field in fields:
    if field.type =="String":
       list_of_fields.append(field.name)
for i in list_of_fields:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(dataset, "{}".format(i)) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0]=row[0].strip()
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

I get an error:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 4, in  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'strip'

I am guessing the value of i in the line

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(dataset, "{}".format(i)) as cursor:
```

is not in the right format.

I have tested a different formatting,  '"{}"'.format(i). It too has an error when put inside UpdateCursor.

This code prints correctly formatted values, with double quoatation marks, which are required for fields inside UpdateCursor

```
>>> for i in list_of_fields:
...     print '"{}"'.format(i)
```

> ...      "WELL_UWI" "WELL_NAME" "ELEV_TYPE" "CURRENT_STATUS"
>   "SPUD_DATE" "COMPLETION" "FIELD" "WL_COUNTY" "WL_STATE"
>   "DRILLING_OPERATOR" "CURRENT_WELL_LEASE_NAME" "REMARK"

```
for i in list_of_fields:
...     with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(dataset, '"{}"'.format(i)) as cursor:
...         for row in cursor:
...             row[0]=row[0].strip()
...             cursor.updateRow(row)
```

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 10, in  RuntimeError: Cannot find field '"WELL_UWI"'

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The values in the `list_of_fields` are already strings, the UpdateCursor accepts either a list of fields or a string with the name of the field. There is no need to do any kind of formatting to the values.

just do:

```
for i in list_of_fields:
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(dataset, i) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            row[0]=row[0].strip()
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Also are you trying to get rid of all empty spaces or just at the beginning and end of the string? If you want to get rid of all spaces you should use `string.replace(' ','')`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried that. It gives the following error: 
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: That probably means that you have Null data in the field. You can check if the value is Null before you try to do the strip by doing `if row[0] is not None:` or by using a try/except block and excepting out the Attribute error.

Answer (score 0):

After some trail and error this worked:

```
for i in list_of_fields:
     with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(dataset, i) as cursor:
         for row in cursor:
            row[0]=str(row[0]).strip()
            cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to do this, this covers up your error by converting the Null values to a string value of 'None'. Instead of converting to string you should just check if the value is None before you try to strip it.